# Let $\ f_1:A \rightarrow B$ and $\ f_2:A \rightarrow B$. Prove or disprove $f_1 \cap f_2$ iff $f_1=f_2$.

Tags: functions, proof-writing

Here is the question I am working on (screenshot):

---

[image]

---

So, I haven't worked with function proofs very much (especially in the context of iff statements and with intersections). I am looking to see if I am on the right track for how to approach this proof, and to look for feedback in the holes of my proof knowledge.

Strategy: I will prove this statement (not disprove).

Forward:
Prove directly. Let $(x,y) \in f_1 \cap f_2$. This is equivalent to saying that $x \in f_1$ and $x \in f_2$, given by the intersection. *From here, I am uncertain where to go and how to show this indicates $A=B$.*

Converse:
I was thinking that I should proceed by contrapositive. To do the contrapositive, my statement would be "If $A \neq B$, then $f_1 \cup f_2$ is not a function".
*I am much more stuck with the converse direction, so a push in the right direction would be helpful.*

Additional question: Can you prove either side of a biconditional statement by contradiction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, we can think of $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ as subsets of $A \times B$, with $f_{1} = \{(x, f_{1}(x)) \in A \times B  \}$ and $f_{2} = \{(x, f_{2}(x)) \in A \times B  \}$.

Now, we need to prove $f_{1} \cap f_{2}$ is a function from $A$ to $B$ iff $f_{1} = f_{2}$.

Let's prove the forward direction first.  Suppose $f_{1} \cap f_{2}$ is a function from $A$ to $B$.  We want to show $f_{1} = f_{2}$.  Let's do this by contradiction.  So suppose $f_{1} \neq f_{2}$.  Then without loss of generality we can assume there is some $(x, f_{1}(x)) \in f_{1}$ but $(x, f_{1}(x)) \not \in f_{2}$.  Since $(x, f_{1}(x)) \not \in f_{2}$, then the function $f_{1} \cap f_{2}$ cannot be a function from $A$ to $B$ because for it to be one, it should be defined for every input $a \in A$, but for the particular $x$ we isolated above, $f_{1} \cap f_{2}$ is not defined on this $x$ (why?).

Now let's prove the backward direction.  Suppose $f_{1} = f_{2}$.  We want to show $f_{1} \cap f_{2}$ is a function from $A$ into $B$.  Well, let $a \in A$.  What is $(f_{1} \cap f_{2})(a)$?  Well, if we are thinking about $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ as the sets described above, then we consider their intersection.  Since $f_{1} = f_{2}$, for each $a$, $f_{1}(a) = f_{2}(a)$, so $(a, f_{1}(a)) = (a, f_{2}(a))$ for each $a$, which tells us that $f_{1} \cap f_{2}$ as a function takes $a$ to the value $f_{1}(a)$ (which equals $f_{2}(a)$), and this is true for every $a$.  It is up to you to now determine why this proves the statement.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll start to work through this and refine it-- will ask if other questions arise.

Comment: @mia.avery No problem.  I should mention something.  When we say $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$, remember that this means $f$ takes values from $A$ (i.e., inputs) to values in $B$ (i.e., outputs).  And two more things have to be true.  For each $a \in A$ we plug in to $f$ (i.e., for every input), there must be some output $b \in B$ such that $f(a) = b$.  Also, you cannot have any single element $a \in A$ being sent to two different elements in $B$ (this is what we call "well defined").

Comment: Make a special note that just because each element in $A$ has an output in $B$ assigned to it doesn't necessarily mean every element in $B$ has some input in $A$ being assigned to it.  If each $b \in B$ has some $a \in A$ being mapped to it, we say the function is *onto*.  Also make another special note: just because no single element in $A$ can go to two different places, doesn't mean no element in $B$ can have two different elements from $A$ being mapped to it.  If we can say for each $b \in B$ that there is *at most* one $a \in A$ being mapped to it, then we would say $f$ is *one-to-one*.

Comment: Thanks for the supplemental notes. When we have a function that's both one-to-one and onto, this is when we can state that the function is bijective-- correct? Not sure if we use surjective (onto) and injective (one-to-one), but I've heard them tossed around.

Comment: @mia.avery Yes, you're right about everything!